# Is there a synonym for Thanks?

Tags: synonyms

I was asked this question by a friend today, and the question really beats me. I know that *gracias* and *merci* are like practical workarounds, but is there no synonym for Thanks in English?

Comment: 'Preciate it, man.

Comment: Maybe you can find synonymous expressions  in answers to: [Popular alternatives to “thank you”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90692/popular-alternatives-to-thank-you)

Comment: What do you need a synonym for 'Thanks' for? Do you also need a synonym for 'horse'?

Comment: Probably a hundred different fairly common synonyms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One word to replace thanks is "**Appreciated**". Which is kind of using the word as informal slang and short for "This/It is appreciated"

Only other single word I can think to replace "thanks" is "**Gratitude**" or "***Gratitudes***" (the latter of which I don't believe is an actual word). But that would be using the word informally as well. And I believe is quite uncommon usage. But saying "thanks" to mean "thank you" is just as informal and could be considered slang but it is so commonly used.

Because formally "thanks" should be used like: "We give thanks to the lord for our food." or "I wanted to express my thanks."

Some other ways of saying thanks:

- You're too kind
- I owe you one
- Much obliged
- Bless you
- Or simply a tip of the head or hat in the person you want to thank's direction

Also commonly known thank you's in other languages (2 of which you already named)

- Gracias (Spanish)
- Grazie (Italian)
- Merci (French)
- Arigato (Japanese
- Ni hao (Chinese)
- Danke or Dank (German)

Comment: Really good to see nice, comprehensive answers from new users. +1.

Answer (score 0):

> but is there no synonym for Thanks in English?

<strike>None that I can think of that are used as short interjections.</strike> However, some other options (with varying degrees of seriousness/formality) are:

> I appreciate it.
>
> I'm indebted to you
>
> I'm very grateful.

Some other short options are a little more colloquial:

> Cheers
>
> Ta (just a shorter form of **T**h**a**nks)

The main difference with these is that they all use an object *and* a subject. "Thanks", probably due to it's commonness, has dropped parts of the sentence. In it's full form, "thanks" means:

> I thank you (using thank as a verb)
>
> I give you thanks (using thank as a noun)

---

*Aside*:
Just doing a little research, I came across the archaic term "[gramercy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gramercy)". I like this term and think it should make a comeback!

Comment: I thought "Gramercy" was just the name of a town in southern Louisiana. Thanks!

Comment: If someone said "ta" to me, I might misunderstand and think they were saying "good-bye" and certainly not thanking me.  I think "ta" is British English.  So, it might be misunderstood in the States.